# Identified Performance Discrepancy in my AES addRoundKey: Slower than Expected

Tags: aes, xor

### Problem

I'm working on an AES implementation in C++, and I have been testing the performance of my code, and its functions. I've noticed a significant performance slowdown in my 'addRoundKey' function. The time it takes to complete the 'addRoundKey' function seems to scale linearly, i.e. if I give it 1mb it takes ~650ms, if I give it 5mb it takes ~3,400ms.

### Context

I am not using a AES Library, I am using my own code. To test my code I have been using Google Test to ensure correctness, but also using its execution time to "benchmark" my functions. For each of the function tests below, they take an input of 1mb size. Here are to outputs for the AES function test:

```
[----------] 7 tests from TestAesFunctions
[ RUN      ] TestAesFunctions.SubByte
[       OK ] TestAesFunctions.SubByte (23 ms)
[ RUN      ] TestAesFunctions.shiftRows
[       OK ] TestAesFunctions.shiftRows (26 ms)
[ RUN      ] TestAesFunctions.mixColumns
[       OK ] TestAesFunctions.mixColumns (34 ms)
[ RUN      ] TestAesFunctions.addRoundKey
[       OK ] TestAesFunctions.addRoundKey (650 ms)
[ RUN      ] TestAesFunctions.invSubByte
[       OK ] TestAesFunctions.invSubByte (21 ms)
[ RUN      ] TestAesFunctions.invShiftRows
[       OK ] TestAesFunctions.invShiftRows (25 ms)
[ RUN      ] TestAesFunctions.invMixColumns
[       OK ] TestAesFunctions.invMixColumns (33 ms)
[----------] 7 tests from TestAesFunctions (819 ms total)
```

As you can see the 'addRoundKey' function has a significant time increase compared to the rest of the functions. This was unexpected as I would have though the 'addRoundKey' would be super fast because its just XOR, and I didn't think there would be any huge memory searches.

Here is the actual function so you can see:

```
void AES::addRoundKey(std::vector<unsigned char>& input, const std::vector<unsigned char> roundKey, size_t blockIndex, size_t round)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4 * Nb; i++) {
        input[blockIndex + i] ^= roundKey[round * Nb * 4 + i];
    }
}
```

Note that I am doing all my operations in place to hopefully increase performance by not needing to copy to a separate state array and doing the operations on that, then copying into an output. This the indexing could be a little hard to read. So here is where the function is used:

```
void AES::encryptBlock(std::vector<unsigned char>& input, const std::vector<unsigned char> roundKey, size_t blockIndex)
{
    addRoundKey(input, roundKey, blockIndex, 0);

    size_t round = 1;
    while (round < Nr) {
        subByte(input, blockIndex);
        shiftRows(input, blockIndex);
        mixColumns(input, blockIndex);
        addRoundKey(input, roundKey, blockIndex, round); // Update round key index for each round
        ++round;
    }

    subByte(input, blockIndex);
    shiftRows(input, blockIndex);
    addRoundKey(input, roundKey, blockIndex, round);
}
```

and Nb is a constant variable for the "number of blocks" so **Nb = 4**.

*edit: Here is the actual test for 'addRoundKey', here you can see the 1mb of data I am generating (which is multithreaded so it +~12ms to the test), and I am not testing for correctness as I can't if I am generating random data.

```
TEST(TestAesFunctions, addRoundKey) {
    AES aesObject;
    // Prepare input data
    std::vector<unsigned char> inputData = generateRandomData(1);
    std::vector<unsigned char> state = inputData;

    // Call the addRoundKey function and test
    for (size_t blockIndex = 0; blockIndex < state.size(); blockIndex += 16) {
        aesObject.addRoundKey(state, hexStringToBytesVec("10a58869d74be5a374cf867cfb473859"), blockIndex, 0);
    }

    // Check if the output matches the expected output
    EXPECT_EQ(true, true);
}
```

It should be fine to just use on 128-bit key as I am just using round = 0, so it should just keep reusing the same given key.

### Questions

1. Is there anything wrong with my approach that is hurting the performance, or is that expected for 'addRoundKey' to be the slowest part of AES?
2. Are there any recommended optimizations or alternate approaches for 'addRoundKey' that could improve the efficiency?

Note that I want to keep the specifications that we are doing things in-place of my input vector.

Any insights, suggestions or optimizations that better explain this discrepancy is appreciated. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here's a pair of timing experiments to try: (1) loop [unroll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling#Static/manual_loop_unrolling), since there's only 16 iterations anyway; (2) tell XOR to **read** from two arrays and **write** to a third array, followed by memcpy() to put the result where it belongs. // Also, verify your arrays begin on cache-line alignment. And ask the [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org) about the code being generated by the optimizer switches you're providing.

Comment: When you are benchmarking addRoundKey, do you use the same input/roundKey/round input repeatedly, or do you use different inputs/roundKeys/allow round to increase beyond 11 or 15?  One possibility (if you consistently use inputs from different memory locations) is that the benchmarks is seeing cache misses (which you likely won't see much of in the actual code).  That is, your benchmark code might be giving you misleading results.

Comment: @poncho Yes I am using the same input (state), key, and in my addRoundKey test I am using a for loop to go though each block. I will add the test I made for addRoundKey to the question so you can see it.

Comment: Two things: 1) how fast is `hexStringToBytesVec("10a58869d74be5a374cf867cfb473859")` (and if it does dynamic allocation, how long does that allocation/deallocation take)?  Is that's what taking up the time?  2) you increase blockIndex by 16 every iteration, and so likely you are running into cache misses.  Either may be causing what you see...

Comment: @poncho I have not tested hexStringToBytesVec, but every other test uses it, so if that was the bottleneck we would probably see the same problem for each function. Also every other test has the same for loop and 16 blockIndex iteration as the inputs are the same structure and type. All other tests are basically the same except for the actual function call in the for loop. So if that were the case wouldn't we have the same cache miss in every test? Or is it special because we have two parameters (Input, roundKey) that addRoundKey has and the others don't?

Comment: @Lachlan: the other tests may use it, but do they use it within the loop?  The addRoundKey test uses it to generate the simulated subkey (which no other function uses).  BTW: it should be simple enough to move that call outside the loop (so and it is called just once...)

Comment: @poncho Ah, yeah that was a good point. I did your suggestion, and the time is now ~43ms. So thank you! Sadly I was kinda hoping the function was slowing everything down because my encryption/ decryption are still ~900ms for 1mb of data which is pretty slow. I guess I need to do some more digging in my code to see why because the individual functions test execution sum is only ~190ms for 1mb data. So I am now very confused why encryption and decryption are slow :). Thanks for the help though!

Comment: This is exactly the time that you don't want to use classes such as `std:vector` instead of directly referencing an array. You could possibly get away with that in an API but please do not inside of the function. I'm a big fan of collection frameworks, but they are often in the way when squeezing out performance especially if they are used over basic types such as words. Bounds checking, dereferencing, hidden function calls....

Comment: @J_H "(2) tell XOR to read from two arrays and write to a third array, followed by memcpy() to put the result where it belongs." Can you indication to us on how that is faster than `^=`? I really don't see how using more memory will help at all. Not saying that it isn't but it goes against my ad hoc knowledge and intuition.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes it was just a shot in the dark. I agree with OP that mutating an array _should_ be fast. But repeated writes to same cache line _can_ sometimes lead to a cache line pinging around. I just wanted a simple {read, read, write} setup with an observed timing measurement that lets us rule it out and move on to other hypotheses. // Oh, good! Turns out that too many calls to `hexStringToBytesVec()` was the culprit. Our sanity is saved.

Comment: @J_H " ~900ms for 1mb of data which is pretty slow" ... so yeah, still not well optimized.

Comment: BTW: why are you writing your own AES implementation anyways?  If you want high performance, it's hard to beat the OpenSSL implementation (even without AES_NI).  If you want side channel resistance, well, I expect you'll need to revise your entire approach...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yeah I know it isn't best to use a vector. My original approach was using an state array that I copied the input into and did my operations on that array. But I was seeing if it would be any faster to not need to copy my input and just do everything in-place with my input vector. Since I can't know what size of data someone will input it was my first instinct to use a vector. Both approaches with the state array and vector are very close in performance though.

Comment: @poncho I have been creating my own implementations of primitives out of hobby (and for my resume) and have been combining them into a sort of library for my github. So I was trying to make it better, even though I totally agree someone shouldn't use my code and just use openssl. Its also curious because I've been working on another project in Rust with a friend and we added AES, and its very similar code but runs at ~200ms for encryption and we though a C++ implementation would be a fun comparison. But my C++ implementation is surprisingly quite a bit slower than the rust one.

Comment: At the time you are using a function such as `add round keys` you should not be handling user input anymore. For AES you can optimize for specific configurations (AES-128 / 192 / 256) of course. Even things like `blockIndex < state.size()` can be optimized. Compilers are really great nowadays, but just having a literal there could make a bit of a difference compared to a call.